# Thunderbolt 3 to triple HDMI

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, thunderbolt

My notebook (Dell Precision 5520) has `Thunderbolt 3`.

Thunderbolt 3 provide 40Gbps (double the speed of Thunderbolt 2).

In terms of video it has
8 lanes of DisplayPort 1.2 (High Bit RTE 2 (HBR2) and MST).

It should support two 4K 60 Hz displays.
But I don't need 4K screens. I need Full HD screens, but I need not 2, but 3 of them.

When I look at specifications for Docking stations, I see that those of them that provide 3 screens require "`HBR3 or Displayport 1.4`" or "`DP1.4 with DSC`". What if I get one of them?

My question is - will I have a 3 screen docking station working from my Thunderbolt 3?

Because from the bandwidth perspective it sounds like more than enough for 3 FullHD screens.
And 8 lanes of DisplayPort 1.2 should cover 3 screens.

But, maybe there is another reason to request `HBR3` or `Displayport 1.4` to work with these docking statins?

Comment: "And 8 lanes of DisplayPort 1.2 should cover 3 screens." - So are you asking about DisplayPort or HDMI?  Why do you talk about docking stations that support DisplayPort 1.4 instead of HDMI?  Your question is really confusing.

Comment: I'm talking about Thunderbolt 3, which is USB 3.1 Type-C connector being converted to HDMI connector. Displayport, in my question, is a reference to a specification, it is not a connector type.

Comment: DisplayPort and HDMI are two very different standards.  You are talking about Type-C in [HDMI ALT mode](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec).  **DisplayPort most certainly is a connector type, it's also a standard, but that's beside the point.**

Comment: The question isn't confusing at all. Thunderbolt uses DisplayPort (the protocol) to transport video data, always. Whether that's converted to HDMI afterwards or not is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

While Thunderbolt 3 certainly does appear to support 8 DisplayPort lanes, that’s “up to”. It is unlikely docking station makers or even PC makers would go all-in on this when they can save money by not doing so.

That being said, even with DisplayPort 1.2 (HBR2, 5.4 GBit/s/lane), you can *easily* do a 1080p60 stream in a single lane, so a Thunderbolt 2/3 connection (4 lanes minimum) can drive 4 displays like that no problem.

In the end, with poor documentation and virtually no reviews pushing the limits, there’s only one possibility: Get one, try it, return it if it doesn’t work.

Comment: maybe, as you said "can easily do a 1080p60 stream in a single lane", but single lane is not enough for connecting a screen.
A standard DisplayPort connection has 4 lanes. BUT Lanes are used for transmission of video and audio. Audio is not needed in case of multiple screens on the same computer, thus we are getting a free lane. Yes, DisplayPort AUX channel is still needed for EDID (I2C) or CEC commands - maybe they would reserve a lane for them. And another lane for reverse data. So 3 lanes per screen would be enough. But I only have 2!

Comment: Lanes are entirely separate from all other aspects of a DisplayPort connection. Otherwise a MST hub could not allow two screens on two-lane DisplayPort over USB-C.

Comment: Yes, you are right. DisplayPort 1.2 added support for Multi-Stream Transport (MST), enabling multiple monitors to be used via a single DisplayPort connector. But in this case I have no idea how lanes work.

Answer (score 1):

I bought [Dell Thunderbolt Dock (WD19TBS)](https://www.dell.com/en-au/work/shop/dell-thunderbolt-dock-wd19tbs/apd/210-azdd/pc-accessories) it worked fine. It allowed me to utilize 3 FullHD displays just fine. It was actually more than FullHD, it was 1920x1200, thus the `Thunderbolt-3` can do it.

But there was a catch. My notebook (Dell Precision 5520) can only run 3 displays. So if I use 3 external displays with my docking station, my laptop displays is getting turned off.

My notebook (Dell Precision 5520) is not the only one suffering from it. It is a new trend, new laptops these days have kind of 2 video cards. In my case it is `Nvidia Quadro M1200` with 4Gb of video memory and `Intel HD Graphics 630` with shared memory. `Nvidia Quadro M1200` - designed to have no video outputs, it works like a "slave". `Intel HD Graphics 630` - is a "master" in this context. So the "master" sends all the heavy calculations to be processed by the "slave" and only displays what is returned by the "slave". Thus, even having 4GB of video memory and "Nvidia Quadro" on board, the overall configurations still limited to the number of screens that the "master" video card can provide.

Lucky we have [displaylink](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/525038-displaylink-display-resolution-support) on the market, they make chipsets that work like external video cards. For example DL-6950 chipset has 2 outputs, the maximum resolution is 3840x2160 (UHD) if both video outputs are being used. This chip is used to build a number of Adapters. Popular Startech [USB32DP24K60](https://www.startech.com/en-au/audio-video-products/usb32dp24k60) [USBA2DPGB](https://www.startech.com/en-au/cards-adapters/usba2dpgb) and little known [ELECABLE](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B094G5JLNC)